# Internationalization(i18n) Or Localization

Tags: apache-flex, localization, internationalization, flex4

I am developing a flex application where I want to use Localization or i18n to support multiple languages.

I don't want to embed property files so that I can change the properties at run time.

Is it Possible in Flex.

I am using

- FleshBuilder 4.7
- flex SDK 4.6
- Flash Player 11.1.0

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can manually load a resource properties file and create resource bundles dynamically. Check the LoadResourceBundleOperation code from the AS3Commons Async project for an example: http://as3-commons.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/as3-commons-async-flex/src/main/actionscript/org/as3commons/async/operation/impl/LoadResourceBundleOperation.as